# Getting a nullreference exception while reading a xml file of a rss

Tags: c#, xml

```
            try
            {
                rssDoc = new XmlDocument();
                // Load the XML context into XmlDocument
                rssDoc.Load(rssReader);
                MessageBox.Show(rssDoc.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               errorProvider1.SetError(url, "Cannot load the RSS from this url");
            }
            // Loop for <rss> tag in xmldocument
            for (int i = 0; i < rssDoc.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                // If <rss> tag found
                if (rssDoc.ChildNodes[i].Name == "rss")
                {
                    // assign the <rss> tag node to nodeRSS
                    nodeRss = rssDoc.ChildNodes[i];
                }
            }
            //Loop for the <channel> tag in side <rss> tag stored in nodeRss
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeRss.ChildNodes.Count; i++)  <<<<<<EXCEPTION
            {
                // <channel> node found
                if (nodeRss.ChildNodes[i].Name == "channel")
                {
                    //assign the <channel> tag to nodeChannel 
                    nodeChannel = nodeRss.ChildNodes[i];
                }
            }
```

Above code is working fine for most of the rss feeds but I am getting a nullrefrence exception while going through the last loop.
What should i do to make it work?

Comment: Not really related to the problem but why don't you loop with a `foreach`? It's much easier to read.

Comment: In what line exactly does the `NullReferenceException` occur? In the loop body or in one of the statements in the loop head itself? A good start for finding out what's wrong when a `NullReferenceException` is thrown is resolving chained references such as `nodeRss.ChildNodes[i].Name` step by step and saving all intermediate values in variables - this way, you can find out whether `nodeRss`, `nodeRss.ChildNodes`, `nodeRss.ChildNodes[i]` and `nodeRss.ChildNodes[i].Name` are `null`, respectively.

Comment: I'm *guessing* that it's either `nodeRss` or `nodeRss.ChildNodes` that evaluates to `null`. Both of those are declared outside of the code snippet shown but in that case it's a fairly safe bet that the `<rss>`-finding `for` loop finds no matches. Do double-check your XML input or post a full code snippet along with XML that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel?

```
XmlNode nodeChannel = rssDoc.SelectSingleNode("/rss/channel");
```

...should do the trick. (I'm pretty sure RSS only allows a single `channel` element inside the root `rss` element. Otherwise, look at [`SelectNodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx) rather than `SelectSingleNode()`.)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop code is not inside of the try block. You should change this first, then you should use XDocument and ForEach. Also take a look what @Michael Kjörling wrote.

```
try
{
    XDocument rssDoc = new XDocument(rssReader);

    foreach(var ele in rssDoc.Elemtens["rss"])
    {


    }
    foreach(var ele in rssDoc.Elemtens["channel"])
    {


    }
}    
catch (Exception ex)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(url, "Cannot load the RSS from this url");
}
```